# How to pass material-ui's theme object to defaultProps?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

In React, I have a functional component that validates props and implements default props for any non-required props. I'm also using mui's `makeStyles` to grab the `theme` object to apply styling to my components.

My question is **how does one go about passing the `makeStyles` theme object down to the `defaultProps` to avoid hard keying values?**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  componentStyle: {
    color: `${theme.palette.light.main}`,  // just like how I'm accessing `theme` here, I'd like to access in `defaultProps`
  },
  componentContainer: ({ backgroundColor }) => {
    return { backgroundColor };
  },
}));


const Example = ({ backgroundColor }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ backgroundColor });

  return (
    <div className={classes.componentStyle} >
      <div className={classes.componentContainer} /> // use default styling using `theme` if none is provided
    </div>
  )

}


Example.propTypes = {
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
};


Example.defaultProps = {
  backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.light.main}`,  // I want to access `theme` here and do the following. While `backgroundColor: 'white'` will work I want to avoid hard keying values. 
};


export default Example;
```

EDIT: based on the solution provided by @Fraction below is what I'll move forward with.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  componentStyle: {
    color: `${theme.palette.light.main}`,
  },
  componentContainer: ({ backgroundColor }) => {
    return { 
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor || `${theme.palette.light.main}`
    };
  },
}));


const Example = ({ backgroundColor }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ backgroundColor });

  return (
    <div className={classes.componentStyle} >
      <div className={classes.componentContainer} />
    </div>
  )

}


Example.propTypes = {
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
};


Example.defaultProps = {
  backgroundColor: null, 
};


export default Example;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `makeStyles`'s theme object down to the `defaultProps`, just use the [Logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_2) to set the `backgroundColor` property to `theme.palette.light.main` when the passed argument is any falsy value, e.g: (`0`, `''`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`):

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  componentStyle: {
    color: `${theme.palette.light.main}`,  // just like how I'm accessing `theme` here, I'd like to access in `defaultProps`
  },
  componentContainer: ({ backgroundColor }) => ({ 
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor || theme.palette.light.main,
  }),
}));
```

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet but to complete what you wrote, would I be correct to say, by setting a default value for `backgroundColor` in the parameter, it will not get overwritten by whatever value I have assigned to the `defaultProps`. Essentially I can set the `defaultProps` value for `backgroundColor` to `null`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, the `backgroundColor` property would take the `theme.palette.light.main` value only if the `backgroundColor` argument is evaluated to any falsy value

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to not pass theme as prop, but to use Theme context.

I do that in all apps which I am working on and it is flexible and prevents props drilling as well.

In your top level component, e.g. `App.tsx` put the Material UI theme provider:

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import DeepChild from './my_components/DeepChild';

const theme = {
  background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
};

function Theming() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <DeepChild />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Then, in your components which need a theme:
(as per https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#accessing-the-theme-in-a-component):

```js
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

function DeepChild() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <span>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</span>;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm just rubber ducking something here. Since I'm still passing `backgroundColor` as a prop to my `Example` component I'm just wondering how to address it there. I really don't want to hard code any values in my `defaultProps`. I should mention I don't have TS implemented with this app. I'm all for using the `ThemeProvider` but I won't be able to use `useTheme` within my `defaultProps`.